# Suppress all git warnings

Tags: git, matlab

I'm calling git log from MATLAB to find out last commit hash and get a *'terminal is not fully functional'* warning.

I don't want to fiddle around various git settings or exporting the right TERM variable (tried TERM=dumb - didn't work).

Is there a way to supress **all** git warnings, or at least make git not require pressing enter after each of them?

Comment: TERM should not matter. What matters is that git connected with terminal with its stdout. Usually if git is called with popen(), of its output is redirected it should detect that there is no terminal and disable the pager. How do you call it from matlab? Are you reading its output? Maybe it worth adding some matlab-specific tag

Comment: @max630 I called with system(), however pager was not disabled. Had to press enter within MATLAB command window

Comment: I was wrong about system(). it does not redirect input and output, so git still should use pager. But how does matlab read the output then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the answer is to use --no-pager option e.g. like this

```
git --no-pager log -1 --format="%H"
```

But to answer question in title, use `2>/dev/null`, like:

```
git status 2>/dev/null
```